# Do you know whether Mac app store approve the application using CGSPrivate.h?

Tags: macos, app-store

I'm just curious about it.

I'm developing the Mac application using CGSPrivate.h header.

I heard that CGSPrivate has hidden APIs and Apple doesn't accept the application using private APIs.

However, in my thinking, CGSPrivate.h is not private because it can use APIs in Cocoa Framework.

Give me exact answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGSPrivate` is apart of a Private framework, so your app will be rejected, you have heard correctly.

Just because a private framework interacts with a public framework does not mean that Apple will allow developers to use it and distribute that app in the Mac App Store, however, you are welcome to distribute it by other means, but there is a chance that your app will break down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Public APIs are those documented and supported by Apple. So no, "CGSPrivate.h" does not contain public APIs and you cannot use it in apps destined for the App Store.

If you choose to distribute your app outside of the App Store, you can use private APIs but risk breaking in new versions of Mac OS X.